# herencia de clases que se encuentran en archivos diferentes

Tags: javascript

quizá sea lo más sencillo del mundo pero no doy con la clave...

Pues la cosa es que tengo la clase "Persona" en el archivo "24.2.js" y la clase hija en el archivo "25.html".
 He hecho un enlace al archivo 24.2.js desde el script, pero solo reconoce la clase "persona" y no, la clase Alumno (cargando la consola desde 25.html)

Espero haberme explicado bien...
Muchas gracias

25.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
<title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<script src="24.2.js">
    class Alumno extends Persona{
        constructor(nombre, edad, peso, nota){
            super(nombre, edad, peso);
            this.nota = nota;
        }
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

24.2.js:

```
class Persona{
constructor(nombre, edad, peso){
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.edad = edad;
    this.peso = peso;
}

mostrar(){
    alert(this.nombre + " " + this.edad);
}

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estás reusando un elemento `script` tanto para incluir un fichero JS, como para añadir un script anónimo nuevo. Prueba a utilizar dos elementos `script` diferentes, uno para cada cosa:

```
<script src="24.2.js"></script>
<script>
    class Alumno extends Persona {
        constructor(nombre, edad, peso, nota) {
            super(nombre, edad, peso);
            this.nota = nota;
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Así es Ordago, muchas gracias!   :)